i cant setup input and output split in vs code it is showing the following problem when i compile it
Executing task:  copy "D:\cpp\introduction\firstclass.cpp" D:\cpp\jspwTest.cpp && g++ jspwTest.cpp -o jspwTest && jspwTest < input.txt > output.txt && del jspwTest.exe && del jspwTest.cpp
    1 file(s) copied.

The system cannot find the file specified.

The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c  copy "D:\cpp\introduction\firstclass.cpp" D:\cpp\jspwTest.cpp && g++ jspwTest.cpp -o jspwTest && jspwTest < input.txt > output.txt && del jspwTest.exe && del jspwTest.cpp" terminated with exit code: 1.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

i was expecting an output but there was an error

Try this modified command:
copy "D:\cpp\introduction\firstclass.cpp" "D:\cpp\jspwTest.cpp" && g++ "D:\cpp\jspwTest.cpp" -o "D:\cpp\jspwTest" && "D:\cpp\jspwTest" < "D:\cpp\input.txt" > "D:\cpp\output.txt" && del "D:\cpp\jspwTest.exe" && del "D:\cpp\jspwTest.cpp"
This command uses the full file path at each step, which can help avoid some common file not found problems. If your input.txt file is not in the D:\cpp\ directory, you will need to replace D:\cpp\input.txt in the command with the correct path.
